# Wrong german character count in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, character, utf

I am making a quiz website where german is the main language.
in PHP, When i count this text => "(ä, ö, ü and ß)", it return total 19 chars but in Javascript (in browser) it count as 15.

```
//- PHP
strlen("(ä, ö, ü and ß)"); // - returns 19
//- JS
"(ä, ö, ü and ß)".length; //- return 15
```

I need to make them equal. is it possible?

Comment: `strlen()` returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string. Please read the official guide [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Comment: "***Note:** `strlen()` returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.*" from [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php). So, what do you want to do - count the bytes in JS or count the characters in PHP?

Comment: Hints: The length property of a String object in Javascript contains the length of the string, in UTF-16 code units, `strlrn` function in PHP returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

Answer (score 2):

How i write in the comment `strlen` will return number of bytes instead you can use `mb_strlen` like:

```
echo mb_strlen("(ä, ö, ü and ß)", 'utf8'); // output 15
```

Link:

- [strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)
- [mb_strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use TextEncoder Javascript native API to convert the string from UTF-16 to UTF-8 format and then get the length as bytes.

```
var encodedText = new TextEncoder().encode("(ä, ö, ü and ß)");
console.log(encodedText.length);
```

Please note it does not work in IE. Refer [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder)